# Difference between QR code generation for qr code version 2 and qr code version 4 using Zxing library in android

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I am trying to generate qr code using Zxing library for qr code version 4 in android but i am unable to perform that .
Any kind of suggestion or link would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: I tried it with qr code version 2 and it is working fine but i want it for qr code version 4 .How to do that ?

Comment: What have you tried? What is going wrong? Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I tried generating qr code version 2 using ZXing library and it is successfully generating that one but what i want to know is -what is the difference between qr code version 2 and version 4 while generating qr code .This is the link from which i took help -http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/09/android-generate-qr-code-using-zxing.html

Answer (score 0):

Version is chosen by the algorithm, you can't control it. The more data you have (and the more complex is the data, such as alphanumeric vs byte which is more complex) the higher version you will get.

Version 2 means there will be 17 + 2 x 4 modules (25). Version 4 will have 17 + 4 x 4 = 33 modules.

You can find some details on Denso Wave's [website](http://www.qrcode.com/en/about/version.html).